# sending login data in json format to server side using POST method in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

I'm trying to send username and password to server side using POST method in objective,but each time I'm getting HTTP-Response code 415..i.e Unsupported Media Type and everytime it gets login whether i give wrong user name or password. Please guys...I seriously need help.. Thanks..
Here is my code..

```
-(void) alertStatus:(NSString*)msg :(NSString*)title
{
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title  message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alertView show];
}


- (IBAction)loginAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSString*username = _userNameField.text;
NSString*password = _passwordField.text;
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username=%@&Passworda=%@" ,username,password];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://172.31.144.227:8080/Analytics/rest/login/post"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length" ];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSMutableDictionary*jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSLog(@"Hello= %@", jsonDict);

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DASHBOARDSEGUE" sender:sender];
if ([response statusCode] ==415) //&& [response statusCode] <417)
{
NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSLog(@"Random Output= %@", jsonObject);
if([jsonObject objectForKey:@"error"])
{
[self alertStatus:@"X" :@"Y"];
} else {
[self alertStatus:@"A" :@"B"];
}
}else{
if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
[self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? From the description, the server always returning successful login, sounds like a server problem...

Comment: yes..I checked the server log and noticed that it's posting null value. Then I added some extra lines     postData = [postData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [postData length] - 1)];
    NSData*jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:postData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];  after the line NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; inorder to convert the data into json object, but the json object gives the null value..

Comment: Check the error returned

Comment: In your code, you have this line
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username=%@&Passworda=%@" ,username,password];    what is 'Passworda'

Comment: Yes..I've already changed it to password and now the issue is fixed.. Thanks for your suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username=%@&Passworda=%@" ,username,password];
```

you use `Passworda` instead of `Password`, maybe check if this is correct?

Did you try to check if your request is correct (with postman for example)?

Good luck!